# TFS 2018 process template editor gone?

Tags: tfs, tfs-process-template

I have scoured the internet for a Process template editor for TFS 2018. We used to have a TFS 2013 on premise version and when i edit work item types, i normally do it in process editor in Visual studio since its easier with the GUI than doing the witadmin import/export. Since we moved to TFS 2018, the process editor i have installed is not working anymore and figured that we might need a new version to be installed compatible for TFS 2018. When i searched for it, i only found this [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KarthikBalasubramanianMSFT.TFSProcessTemplateEditor). Is there any way we can edit a template via GUI on TFS 2018?

Comment: They've changed the WITs (in TFS 2017 I think), and added a new section for web layout (used in the web portal).   I remember using the process template editor for TFS 2018 WITs, but it didn't handle the web layout section so I wound up making changes by hand.

Answer (score 2):

No any way can edit a wit template via GUI on TFS 2018 itself.

You have to prepare the compatible version of Visual Studio (VS 2015 or VS 2017) and with **Process Editor** (Power Tools) installed with it. Then you can connect to TFS 2018 and edit work item types with the **Process Editor** via GUI.

- Visual Studio 2015 : [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 
  2015 Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power)
- Visual Studio 2017 : [TFS Process Template Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KarthikBalasubramanianMSFT.TFSProcessTemplateEditor)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the latest VS extension that works with VS 2019, here is the link [Process Template Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.msdevlabs-pte)

Comment: How can the same be done on Visual Studio 2022 ?

Answer (score 1):

BTW, I thought that my Process Editor stopped working as well, but it turns out that the form preview is useless now if you have upgraded to DevOps.  You can define the WebLayout, but you have to do that directly in the XML instead of through the editor.
The editor still works for define fields and workflow and allows you to not have to use the witadmin command line to import and export WIT definition files.